# El proveedor Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 no está registrado office 2016

Tags: oledb

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
He encontrado soluciones para Office 2010 pero desafortunadamente no funcionan para mi.
Estoy en W7 y tengo Office 2016, según he visto el programa que marca este error es de x84, mi SO es de x64 así como Office. Y tengo el mismo problema en un server 2008 con procesos 365. 
¿Aluna sugerencia?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, te recomiendo que entres a dar un paseo por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla :D

Answer (score 0):

esta respuesta es breve, instala el "**Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016**" del siguiente enlace:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Comment: Hola @fredyfx agradezco tu respuesta, ya había probado instalando esos componentes, al descargarlos me da la opción de descargar el x64 y supongo que el otro es el x86. Descargarlo ambos pero al intentar instalar el de x86 me marca un error.  me dice que no puedo instalar el de x32 ya que tengo instalado office x64 que si necesito instalar ese componente que desintale el de x64 e instale de x32. el otro componente (x64) no me pone pero al instalarlo pero no funciona con ese. :/

Comment: de nada bro, bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, te recomiendo que entres a dar un paseo por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla :D Revisaré y si encuentro algo, te aviso :D